# C++ Mapping Constants to Values

Tags: c++

I am working in CodeBlocks with a header file containing constants such as "const string a = "A";" and "const string bm = "B-";." I am trying to map constants like these to other values using the map below, but when i return map[reference to constant] it does not output anything. What is going on?

```
map<string, double> convGPA;
convGPA[a] = 4.0;
convGPA[am] = 3.7;
convGPA[bp] = 3.3;
convGPA[b] = 3.0;
convGPA[bm] = 2.7;
convGPA[cp] = 2.3;
convGPA[c] = 2.0;
convGPA[cm] = 1.7;
convGPA[dp] = 1.3;
convGPA[d] = 1.0;
convGPA[dm] = 0.7;
convGPA[f] = 0.0;
```

Comment: Can you show how are you referring ?

Comment: I first set the reference of another variable to a constant like this: "mLetterGrade = a;." I then say convGPA[mLetterGrade] and it does not return 4.0, it returns nothing.

Comment: Like this `string mLetterGrade = a;`?

Comment: string mLetterGrade; is declared above the code. This variable reference is added to an array (letterGrades[]) where I then say letterGrades[0] = a;. This is the full assignment of mLetterGrade to the constant "a."

Comment: Still no luck reproducing the issue. Please provide  minimal, complete and verifiable example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have edited my comment from before

Comment: Please provide the complete code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you edited your question to provide a complete working program that demonstrates your problem - a [mcve].  I attempted to assemble a program from the hints you've given so far, but [that program](https://ideone.com/TP1HFI) seems to work correctly.